# How to add new line in SELECT Statement in netezza

Tags: netezza

[image: FNAME LNAME TARGET VANITA MALGE VANITA MALGE]

How do I concat two columns with new line in between in Netezza not SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CHR function, and get the argument value from https://www.asciitable.com/ depending on what you mean by ‘new line’. Unix/windows/Mac unfortunately has different definitions, but let’s go with the Unix style:

```
Select 
  FNAME, 
  LNAME, 
  FNAME||chr(10)||LNAME
FROM YOURTABLE
```